# How to store Values in Array/NSMutableArray From Model Class Dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Here i want to store values into an Array from ModelClass response Dictionary.

- Model Class Dictionary Function

```
func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if inwishlist != nil{
            dictionary["Inwishlist"] = inwishlist
        }
        if image != nil{
            dictionary["image"] = image
        }
        if productId != nil{
            dictionary["product_id"] = productId
        }
        if productName != nil{
            dictionary["product_name"] = productName
        }
        if regularPrice != nil{
            dictionary["regular_price"] = regularPrice
        }
        if shortDescription != nil{
            dictionary["short_description"] = shortDescription
        }
        if specialPrice != nil{
            dictionary["special_price"] = specialPrice
        }
        if stockStatus != nil{
            dictionary["stock_status"] = stockStatus
        }
        if type != nil{
            dictionary["type"] = type
        }
        if wishlistItemId != nil{
            dictionary["wishlist_item_id"] = wishlistItemId
        }
        return dictionary
    }
```

- Response i get from API

```
 "products" : [
      {
        "special_price" : "",
        "stock_status" : true,
        "product_id" : "879",
        "type" : "simple",
        "image" : "catalog\/product\/k\/8\/k834_8.jpg",
        "product_name" : "Bourgeat Stainless Steel Saucepan Lid 240mm",
        "regular_price" : "17.4900",
        "wishlist_item_id" : "0",
        "Inwishlist" : "OUT",
        "short_description" : null
      }    

    ]
```

But when I try This code :-

```
let dataS = self.resultGetProductRoot?.response.products[0].toDictionary().keys as! [String]
```

i get this error:-

> Cast from 'Dictionary.Keys?' to unrelated type '[String]' always fails

And when I try This code :-

```
  let dataS = self.resultGetProductRoot?.response.products[0].toDictionary().keys
  var dat = [String]()
  dat = dataS
```

i got below error:-

> Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary.Keys?' to type '[String]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Xcode 7.0 beta 6 in order to have the keys of your `Dictionary` as an `array` you can achieve it like this:

```
let productKeys = self.resultGetProductRoot?.response.products[0].toDictionary().keys
var productKeysList = Array(productKeys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections are very type safe in Swift, it is not like Java/Objective-C for example which are dynamic. So, in this case you would convert the array manually using loops or using functional programming.

For example (using functional programming):

```
let dictionaryOrEmpty = dictionary ?? [:] // Make an empty dictionary if the dictionary itself is nil
let keysCollection = dictionaryOrEmpty.keys
let strings = keysCollection.map { $0.description } // Get the "string representation" of each of the keys
```

You can make it one-liner using the following:

```
let strings = (dictionary ?? [:]).keys.map { $0.description }
```

Performance gain (both memory and time) could be done using the `lazy` collections also (if all what you need is iterate this as a sequence)

```
let strings = (dictionary ?? [:]).keys.lazy.map { $0.description }
```